# How to CodeLive Search in Java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

hey guys am working on a java Dynamic web application and i wanted to make a live search to fetch cities from the database and suggest them to the user in JSP.

please advise me where to get started?
thanks in advance

Comment: IMO that's a little broad for SO. What problems are you facing? You already stated you want to search in the database so what's the problem in doing that?

Comment: I suggest an REST interface, which offers cities when calling `/cities` with a GET request. Whenever the client types a character (more commonly two or three characters and after a delay of a few hundred milliseconds) you query the endpoint for cities. In the end this is not really a question for this site (little too broad), but if you face any issues you may come back here and were glad to help.